# Stop listening to snapshot updates in cloud firestore in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to stop listening to snapshot updates. The snapshot keeps listening to updates even after the screen is closed. I am using the below code to listen to the updates.

```
CollectionReference reference = Firestore.instance.collection('Events');
reference.snapshots().listen((querySnapshot) {
  querySnapshot.documentChanges.forEach((change) {
    // Do something with change
  });
})
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your listener is of type `StreamSubscription`, so you can call some helpful methods on your listener such as `cancel()`

```
    CollectionReference reference = Firestore.instance.collection('Events');
StreamSubscription<QuerySnapshot> streamSub = reference.snapshots().listen((querySnapshot) {
  querySnapshot.documentChanges.forEach((change) {
    // Do something with change
  });
});
//somewhere
streamSub.cancel();
```

Comment: cancel your subscription not just "somewhere" but when it won't be needed anymore, usually you would need to override method `dispose()`, like this:   `@override
  void dispose() {
    if(streamSub!= null)
      streamSub.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }`

Comment: Thats perfect.. but what if you are getting the change at a Ref via a StreamProvider? how would i disconnect that? Or are we not able to handle that?

Answer (score 6):

The `listen` method returns a `Subscription`

This class is used to cancel the listening.

You should store inside your state that object to cancel subscription on dispose.

Comment: Remi - I have setup `stream.listen` but it is listening once when screen is loaded by `initState`, Not always when something is added/changed on `Firestore`. Kindly check the issue at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68052839/stream-listen-is-not-called-when-limit-is-added-in-firestore-query-in-dart-flu and suggest me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Any ideas on how to do this with Riverpod? Sitting with this for 4 days now and cant get a listener canceled. Neither Flutter, Firestore is cancelling them on navigation.

Answer (score 4):

Very late answer, but I thought I'd complete the previous answers with a code sample as it might be useful to others.

```
class EventsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  EventsScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _EventsScreenState createState() => _EventsScreenState();
}

class _EventsScreenState extends State<EventsScreen> {
  StreamSubscription<QuerySnapshot> _eventsSubscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // Initialise your stream subscription once
    CollectionReference eventsReference = Firestore.instance.collection('Events');
    _eventsSubscription = eventsReference.snapshots().listen((snapshot) => _onEventsSnapshot);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Build your widget here
    return Container();
  }

  void _onEventsSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    // Remove the setState() call if you don't want to refresh your screen whenever you get a fresh snapshot
    setState(() {
      snapshot?.documentChanges?.forEach(
        (docChange) => {
          // If you need to do something for each document change, do it here.
        },
      );
      // Anything you might do every time you get a fresh snapshot can be done here.
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Cancel your subscription when the screen is disposed
    _eventsSubscription?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

This approach leverages the StatefulWidget's state to handle documents changes.

A better approach would be to use a [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) or the [BLoC pattern](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) so that the subscription to your Firestore is not created and handled in the UI.

Comment: great answer. My question is- If i do use Provider... how would I cancel the listening? Atleast over here i have a subscription.cancel() method... any idea? Or dont you think continuous listening when not required would unnecessarily consume resources?

Comment: Was this resolved ? I'm using redux and have UI -> Thunk middleware -> Service layers. My listener is in middleware layer's method call. How do I call an action to cancel the subscription thats within a different method.

Comment: @JLP-Dev JLP-Dev, I have setup `listen` to `Firestore snapshots()` but having a issue of calling `listen` function. Could you please check and suggest me at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68052839/stream-listen-is-not-called-when-limit-is-added-in-firestore-query-in-dart-flu  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Has anyone made progress on how to cancel the listener with Riverpod/Provider? I just can't it right, 4 days of stress with this already. the listeners are not canceled by themselves at all.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is relating to Flutter and therefore probably to widgets changing on new snapshot events, please consider using [StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html) to easily delegate stream management and build great reactive UIs.

```
Container(
    alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
    color: Colors.white,
    child: StreamBuilder<int>(
      stream: _bids,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {
        List<Widget> children;
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          children = <Widget>[
            const Icon(
              Icons.error_outline,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
              child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),
            ),
          ];
        } else {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.none:
              children = const <Widget>[
                Icon(
                  Icons.info,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                  child: Text('Select a lot'),
                )
              ];
              break;
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              children = const <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  width: 60,
                  height: 60,
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                  child: Text('Awaiting bids...'),
                )
              ];
              break;
            case ConnectionState.active:
              children = <Widget>[
                const Icon(
                  Icons.check_circle_outline,
                  color: Colors.green,
                  size: 60,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                  child: Text('\$${snapshot.data}'),
                )
              ];
              break;
            case ConnectionState.done:
              children = <Widget>[
                const Icon(
                  Icons.info,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  size: 60,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                  child: Text('\$${snapshot.data} (closed)'),
                )
              ];
              break;
          }
        }

        return Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: children,
        );
      },
    )
```

Or just use `snapshot.hasData` and `snapshot.hasError` to switch between showing Circle, error, and actual data.

Answer (score 0):

the correct way is stream.pause()
so the listener will be on pause mode
cancel() destroy the listener and his content

Answer (score 0):

For me, I simply use [take](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/take.html) on the snapshot method. Basically, the same principle as rxjs with Firebase. You take one stream of data and stop listening.

```
return collection
        .withConverter<Discount>(
          fromFirestore: (snapshots, _) => Discount.fromMap(snapshots
              .data()!),
          toFirestore: (discount, _) => discount
              .toMap(),
        )
        .snapshots()
        .take(1); // Take 1 to stop listening to events
```

If you run and print out the *ConnectionState*, you'll see it goes to *Done* once it fetches all the docs in the collection.