# Do I need to dispose Firestore document snapshot or just the listener

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, rxdart

Let's say I have the following:

```
StreamSubscription _exampleQuery;
_exampleQuery = dbUsers
        .document(accID)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((DocumentSnapshot _userDocSnap) {}
```

When I call:

```
_exampleQuery.cancel();
```

Is it possible, that the snapshot listener is somehow still active? It seems like firestore bills me for still active subscriptions that are still active & reading documents.

I am familiar with firestore billing, and know that certain unexpected things may couse reads, but I am almost 100% certain that my subscriptions ain't getting canceled properly.

Comment: Seems like this case is related with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51918047/stop-listening-to-snapshot-updates-in-cloud-firestore-in-flutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cancel a listener, then it will not incur any more document reads from that point on.  If you have an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that proves otherwise, please file a bug report with Firebase support so they can validate it.  But I would be absolutely shocked if there was a bug here.  You are likely incurring extra reads some other way, such as via the console.

Comment: Yeah the console may be it too. I'll do some tests, to figure out what it really is