# Stream listen is not called when limit is added in Firestore query in Dart / Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream, listen

**Stream listen is not called when limit is added in Firestore query in Dart / Flutter**

```
final _startAtTimestamp = Timestamp.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(DateTime.parse('2000-01-01 01:01:01.001').millisecondsSinceEpoch);
```

I have used below code in my `initState()` function:

```
@override
void initState() {
    //
    super.initState();

    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () async {
      // 
      Stream<QuerySnapshot> xstream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('messages')
          .where('encSenderUId', isEqualTo: _loggedInUserId)
          .where('encReceiverUId', isEqualTo: widget.encUId)
          .orderBy('messageId', descending: true)
          .startAt([_startAtTimestamp])
          .limit(1)
          .snapshots();

      xstream.listen((event) {
        //
        print('Hiii, I am listening..');

        //
      }, onDone: () {
        print("Task Done single");
      }, onError: (error) {
        print("Some Error ${error.toString()}");
      });

    });

}
```

Case 1: If I **DO NOT** use `limit()` in query then `listen` message is printed once when screen is rendered first time and also `listen` is called when something is changed in Firestore stream (eg. added new document / removed a document).

Case 2: If I use `limit()` in query then `listen` message is printed once when screen is rendered first time but `listen` is **NOT** called when something is changed in Firestore stream (eg. added new document / removed a document).

I have to use `limit()` to fetch one document according to set `orderBy`. I am 100% sure that `limit()` is not allowing stream to listen any event.

**Firestore structure is as:**

[image]

Kindly suggest how can I use `limit` with `listen' to fix this issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: tried to add `onError` in `listen` method?

Comment: @pskink Thanks dear, I have added `onDone` and `onError` callback methods with listen but system is not going into any of these 3 `listen`, `onDone` and `onError` methods. I have updated question by adding `onDone` and `onError` at the end. Kindly check and suggest me. Thanks.

Comment: Firestore db structure is as https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/9648192?key=613ffaa33876bc5111f6795f2813ea84

Comment: Please include your Firestore structure as a screen shot in the question. Links can break and move and that would make it unavailable to future readers.

Comment: Thanks @Jay I have added the screenshot of `Firestore Structure` with the query. BTW do you have any solution of this issue? Kindly share. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You query (including `.limit(1)`) is processed FIRST, THEN the listener attached - so you are listening for changes to ONE, and ONLY ONE document.  Only changes to THAT DOCUMENT will cause updates.  it DOES NOT re-process the query. Are you TRYING to listen for the MOST RECENT document?

Comment: 1) If I do not add `.limit(1)` in query then it returns me 19 `documents` which are correct but my requirement is to get only One `document` out of those 19 `documents` from `messages` `collection`.

Comment: 2) you are right that snapshot will have only 1 `QuerySnapshotObject` in both one ` document` or 19 `documents` case. We will have to process that `QuerySnapshotObject` further to get one / 19 `documents` and we can use `map` on `QuerySnapshotObject`. It works but adding `.limit(1)` is returning nothing. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated? Thanks.

Comment: You misunderstand.  When you add .limit(1) to the query, the QuerySnapshotObject will *only* ever contain **ONE** object, and only changes to that **ONE** object will trigger an update.  Changing **ANY** other document, or **ADDING** any documents, **WILL NOT** trigger an update - just because the query WOULD result in different document when new documents are added DOESN'T MEAN THE LISTENER WILL BE UPDATED.  The query selects WHICH documents to listen to, and will listen to ONLY those documents - the query IS NOT RE-RUN.

Comment: The ```.onSnapshot()``` listens to the documents selected, **NOT** to the query.