# Flutter Firebase Permission Denied

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin

After i sign out, i try to log in again, yes it logs in succesfully but the problem is, i start to get error [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] but when i restart my application, it works again well. What am i missing?

PS: im logging in with Google.

This is my log in code:

```
Future signInWithGoogle() async {
    // Trigger the authentication flow
    final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();

    // Obtain the auth details from the request
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
        await googleUser!.authentication;

    // Create a new credential
    final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );

    // Once signed in, return the UserCredential
    await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  }
```

This is my sign out code:

```
await _googleSignIn.signOut().then((value) async {
                        await widget.firebaseAuth.signOut().then((value) {
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        });
                      }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
                        print(error);
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                          content: Text("ERROR!! TRY AGAIN"),
                        ));
                      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cloud_firestore/permission-denied` error comes from Firestore (the database), not from Firebase Authentication.

Most likely you have some realtime listeners in your code that require the user to be signed in, and those get rejected by the database once you sign the user out.

You can either [remove the listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51918047/stop-listening-to-snapshot-updates-in-cloud-firestore-in-flutter) by canceling the subscriptions, or you can ignore the errors, as the listeners are also canceled automatically after this error occurs.

Comment: if i ignore the errors will i get still datas from those listeners? what should i do?

Comment: No, the listener got rejected because they (no longer) have permission to access the data. If you want to read the data after signing the user in (again), you'll have to reattach the listener. That's probably precisely why it works after you restart the app, because that's when you attach the listeners. Instead of attaching the listeners on (re)start, my guess is you'll want to do it on sign-in in an auth state listener.

Comment: so how can i reattach my listener?

Comment: The same way you attached them initially, which unfortunately you didn't show in your question. If you attached your listeners as part of building the UI, you'll have to force a repaint of the UI, for example by calling `setState()`.

Comment: i solved by canceling and recall them thanks

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I forgot to activate "google-sign in" as an authentication method in firebase.